# To-do app shows no error, but src .js file won't show

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to programming.

I used src file, no error appears, but does not show app.js file's function.
This is supposed to be the beginning stages of a simple to-do list.

```
<span>What do you want to do today?</span>
<button id="btnAdd">Click for New Item</button>
<ul id="todolist"></ul>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

This is what's in app.js file:

```
function addNewItem(list) {
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.innerText = "Hello";
    list.appendChild(listItem);
}

var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.oneclick = function() {
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What jumps out at me is that .oneclick should probably be .onclick

Works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrYKEw

App.js should be:

```
function addNewItem(list) { var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.innerText = "Hello";
list.appendChild(listItem); }

var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() { addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist")); };`
```